# How to interact with background using UISearchController in swift?

Tags: swift, search, tvos, uisearchcontroller

Currently i am using UISearchController.becomeFirstResponder() to present the keyboard when the app is first launched. I am also using UISearchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false to display the background with the keyboard. However, currently i am not able to interact with the background views or use gesture recognition such as swipe or tap? Is there a way to fix this?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "label1.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.frame = CGRect(x: 213, y: CGFloat(self.view.frame.height), width:       700, height: 208)
    button1.layer.opacity = 0.0
    self.view.addSubview(button1) 

    controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    controller.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false


    self.searchView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.controller.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()


}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post code, including what hasn't worked.

Comment: @sschale I have added code above. Is it possible to interact with the button. Because currently, when i try to swipe down on the TVOS remote touchpad it stops at the keyboard and am not able to go down to the button. I tried doing self.view.addSubview(UISearchController.view) earlier, but that doesn't work either. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Ah this is for tvOS - I'm afraid I don't have experience, but I've changed the tag.

Comment: I think it should be the same as IOS. instead of touching on the screen, i am using the remote. But the functionality should be the same.